# Hiding table content using Media Queries

Tags: asp.net, html, css, media-queries

I Have been using media queries to use responsive CSS and currently I am trying to hide certain table content when viewed on 480px.  I created the Class in the CSS called "hideOnSmall" and then added the tag to the Template Field of "Location" but I have not gotten it to actually work so I must be doing something wrong I have looked up ways to do this and all sources led me to this but if anyone can spot anything I missing or if I am doing something wrong.

CSS:

```
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .page-header h1 small {
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"],
  input[type="radio"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .form-horizontal .controls {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .form-horizontal .control-list {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .form-horizontal .form-actions {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .media .pull-left,
  .media .pull-right {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .media-object {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .modal {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .modal-header .close {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -10px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    position: static;
  }
    .hideOnSmall  {
      display: none !important;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="locationName" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideOnSmall">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLocations" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDSLocations" DataTextField="locationName" DataValueField="locationID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("locationID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSLocations" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [locationID], [locationName] FROM [tblLocation]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("locationName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("locationName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: it works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CxLMt/) seems your code generate not expected html

Comment: Basic debugging techniques--fire the page up in Chrome devtools or equivalent, select an element with the .hideOnSmall class which should get having the rule applied, and make sure it is.